# No shareble content in Linkedin with open graph

Tags: linkedin-api

I´ve got a problem with our webpage: http://www.intershop.de/.
When I want to share a link on Facebook and Google+ it works perfect, but LinkedIn always says, "preview cant be created" but I dont know why.

All meta / open graph tags are correct, I hope you can help me.

THX

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong image sizes (for any type of sharing). The image sizes you should use in your open graph tags should be 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels minimum and at these dimensions.

Your current: https://www.intershop.de/files/Intershop/media/images/banner/homepage-teaser/wide/all/shark.jpg